# Reading from a CSV file with a structure array

Tags: c, csv

I am new to C programming and I wan to try reading from a CSV file and print it out. My CSV file is in a format of:

index,country,years,death rate

1     world

```
         50s     36
         60s     29
         70s     22
```

2 Africa

```
         50s     34
```

209 Tonga

```
         50s     49
         60s     67
```

and so on...

I not sure how to read the end of my CSV file and so my code output only prints up to index 143 while my current CSV file prints up to 204. Can anyone guide me with this?

```
void readRecords(){
    FILE *fptr;
    int i,j,k;
    char line[200], hold[10];

    if((fptr=fopen("data.csv","r"))==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open input file data.csv\n");
    }

    else{
        for(i=0;i<999;i++){
            fgets(line, 200, fptr);

            j=0;
            k=0;
            while (line[j] != ','){     // This while loop extract the country name until a comma is detected
                hold[k++] = line[j++];  // Simply copy all character from each line to the country
            }
            hold[k]='\0';
            myRecords[i].index=atoi(hold);
            j++;


            k=0;
            while (line[j] != ','){     // This while loop extract the country name until a comma is detected
                myRecords[i].country[k++] = line[j++];  // Simply copy all character from each line to the country
            }
            myRecords[i].country[k]='\0';
            j++;


            k=0;
            while (line[j] != ','){     // This while loop extract the country name until a comma is detected
                hold[k++] = line[j++];  // Simply copy all character from each line to the country
            }
            hold[k]='\0';
            myRecords[i].year=atoi(hold);
            j++;


            k=0;
            while (line[j] != ','){     // This while loop extract the country name until a comma is detected
                hold[k++] = line[j++];  // Simply copy all character from each line to the country
            }
            hold[k]='\0';
            myRecords[i].deathrate=atoi(hold);
            j++;

        }

        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

Comment: I am thinking to use EOF to read the end of the CSV file but I am not very sure how to implement it.

Comment: When the end of the file is reached, `fgets` returns `NULL`. Check for that and `break` out of the loop. In general, all file reading functions have a special return value that indicate the end of file, usually `NULL` or the special (integer) value `EOF`.

Comment: Also, take care not to overflow `hold`. 10 characters should be enough to hold integers, but with external input, you can't rely on that.

Comment: A single `while (fgets(line, 200, fptr) != EOF)` is all you need to read all of the line into a buffer. Then you can determine how you want to parse the buffer. `strtok` comes to mind. Also look at `strtol` instead of `atoi`. `strtol` allows you to check what was read, as well as any characters that remain unread. Combining `strtok` and `strtol` would allow you to check the buffer for each line read and determine if it was a `1 world` or `50s 34` type line and act accordingly.

Comment: Also GNU `getline` is the preferred way to read line input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Preferred by whom?

Comment: GNU Programming Tutorial (http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html) `The getline function is the preferred method for reading lines of text from a stream, including standard input.`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried inputing the while (fgets(line, 200, fptr) != EOF) above the  else{
        for(i=0;i<999;i++){
            fgets(line, 200, fptr);

But it doesnt work. It doesnt even read any inputs.

Comment: I would have to see your code. That is exactly the way I read the data file before I switched `fgets`  to `getline`.

Comment: @Jordaniatro You should change `EOF` to `NULL` when using `fgets`. See `man 3 fgets` **fgets() return s on success, and `NULL` on error or when end of file occurs** If you have to use `fgets` then do, but if you have the option, I would recommend `getline` below. It takes care of allocation for you in the buffer and len are set to 0. That becomes much more advantageous when dealing with lines of varying length and unknown composition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply step through the line read by `fgets` or `getline` with a pointer and replace the comma's with `\0` characters and incrementally read each variable as you work down the line. Here is a working implementation given your data file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fptr;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    char *p = NULL;
    char *start = NULL;

    int index = 0;
    char *country;
    int years = 0;
    int deaths = 0;

    if ((fptr=fopen (argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s\n", argv[1]);
    }

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1)
    {
        p = line;

        while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
        *p = '\0';
        index = atoi (line);
        start = ++p;
        while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
        *p = '\0';
        country = strdup (start);
        start = ++p;
        while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
        *p = '\0';
        years = atoi (start);
        start = ++p;
        deaths = atoi (start);

        printf ("idx: %3d   country: %12s  years: %3d  deaths: %3d\n",
                index, country, years, deaths);
    }

    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, given an input `.csv` file in the format:

```
1,world,50s,36
1,world,60s,65
1,world,70s,58
2,africa,50s,37
2,africa,60s,66
2,africa,70s,59
207,tonga,50s,37
207,tonga,60s,66
207,tonga,70s,59
```

Your output would be:

```
idx:   1   country:        world  years:  50  deaths:  36
idx:   1   country:        world  years:  60  deaths:  65
idx:   1   country:        world  years:  70  deaths:  58
idx:   2   country:       africa  years:  50  deaths:  37
idx:   2   country:       africa  years:  60  deaths:  66
idx:   2   country:       africa  years:  70  deaths:  59
idx: 207   country:        tonga  years:  50  deaths:  37
idx: 207   country:        tonga  years:  60  deaths:  66
idx: 207   country:        tonga  years:  70  deaths:  59
```

It is just about as short either way. Using `strtok` or just stepping along the buffer and reading what you need directly. If you take time to read through the code carefully. You will see that all it does is read until it hits a comma, replaces the comma with `\0`, reads from the beginning (or start) to get the information needed, advances the pointer by 1, sets the new 'start' point and then repeats all the way down the buffer. After 'deaths' are read, a final loop makes sure all the characters in the line have been read. The `getline` reads the next line and it continues until no more lines can be read in the .csv file.  I hope this helps. (if it isn't obvious, you give it the csv filename on the command line:

```
$ readcsv dat.csv
```

You already have the data and have it parsed into variables in the above. If you want to make use of structures, you can simply change the storage type from common variables to a structure datatype. Something similar to the following works for an array of structs.

```
int recs = 0;

struct _stats { 
    int index;
    char *country;
    int years;
    int deaths;
};

struct _stats *stats[100];
struct _stats *statsptr = NULL;

if ((fptr=fopen (argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open input file %s\n", argv[1]);
}

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1) {

    p = line;
    statsptr = malloc (sizeof (struct _stats));

    while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
    *p = '\0';
    statsptr->index = atoi (line);
    start = ++p;

    while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
    *p = '\0';
    statsptr->country = strdup (start);
    start = ++p;

    while (*p != ',' && *p != 0) p++;
    *p = '\0';
    statsptr->years = atoi (start);
    start = ++p;

    statsptr->deaths = atoi (start);

    stats[recs] = statsptr;
    recs++;

}

int iter = 0;
for (iter = 0; iter < recs; iter++) {
    printf ("idx: %3d   country: %12s  years: %3d  deaths: %3d\n",
            stats[iter]->index,
            stats[iter]->country,
            stats[iter]->years,
            stats[iter]->deaths);
}
```

Beyond initially declaring a maximum number of pointers to structs, you will need to use a dynamic datatype like a linked-list. (beyond the scope of this discussion).

Comment: hmm, but the thing is I am using a structure so that I could later add more inputs to the following data and display it again.

Comment: I would use a struct as well. In fact, I would read the data into a linked-list. That takes care of knowing the data set size before hand, as you can dynamically allocate after each `getline`. Either use a pointer to an array of structs, or add an additional pointer to `struct-next` and call it a linked list.